# jQuery function doesn't print table grid how I think it should

Tags: jquery, html

http://codepen.io/jacob_johnson/pen/meoBpy

I'm trying to create a dynamic table grid; however, the function I am trying, in my unprofessional opinion, feels like it should work but does not.

```
var height = 2; // Determine <tr> amount
var width = 10; // Determine <td> amount

createTable(height, width);

function createTable(height, width) {
  for (i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    $('#template').append('<tr>');
    for (j = 0; j < width; j++) {
      $('#template').append('<td></td>');
    }
    $('#template').append('</tr>');
  }
}
```

What this is giving me is a html output of:

```
<table id="template" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
  </tbody>
  <td></td>
  <td></td> . . .
  . . . ~20 times?
</table>
```

**This is what I want it to look like:**

```
<table id="template" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td> (10 times)
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td> (10 times)
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What else do you expect it to genrate?

Comment: Are you expecting them to be appended under the `tr`s even though you clearly target the parenting `table` element? Where exactly do you believe you currently put the `td`s inside the `tr`s?

Comment: 2 `<tr></tr>` with 10 `<td></td>` wrapped inside?

Comment: @Roope but shouldn't it append to the table element following the intial `<tr>` call? Then close with `</tr>`?

Comment: If you append to a `table`, then how should it go inside a `tr`? The appended element goes inside the selected element.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood `append`. It obviously doesn't perform those actions simultaneously so my mind tricks me to think I was appending following the last HTML written within the `table`. It was my understanding, at first, that I was adding HTML to directly follow whatever else I put in. This does not work since the HTML I inserted is a separate element and not plain text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is wrong, everytime you are appending to the `table`.

**FYI**: jQuery `.append("<tr>")` will append the closing tag automatically as it is not handling with the string but HTML DOM Objects and Elements.

Just do

```
function createTable(height, width) {
  var _html = "";
  for (i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    _html += '<tr>';
    for (j = 0; j < width; j++) {
       _html += '<td></td>';
    }
    _html += '</tr>';
    
  }
  $('#template').append(_html);
}
```

Less DOM Manipulation. More memory efficient.

[Play it here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qOvPee)

Comment: @JacobJohnson This is building the html piece by piece. You are doing whole transactions/operations at a time.

Comment: @Roope Yup. I understand now. Thank you. You comment on my actual question helped me understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var height = 2; // Determine <tr> amount
        var width = 10; // Determine <td> amount

        createTable(height, width);

        function createTable(height, width) {
          for (i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            $('#template').append('<tr class="dynTR">');
          }

          for (j = 0; j < width; j++) {
              $('.dynTR').append('<td></td>');
            }
        }
```

Comment: Creating an extra class is unnecessary.

Comment: Also, wouldn't this append to every single `<tr>` element then? Since they're all a class of the same. This would only work if I had 1 row?

Comment: It will append to all the tags that match with the class name.